# Get data from a column with respect to data from another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Agh6MIWO2pTcdE0yanV0ZkQwWlR6WGxPQUc1T1YtQmc&usp=sharing

```
MASTER_ID                           END_DATETIME    media_file
1390962109139_635_787802027.    1/29/2014 5:21:41   d:\songs_new\target uganda\welcome56060_l.wav
1390962109139_635_787802027.    1/29/2014 5:21:48   d:\songs_new\target uganda\pending_e.wav
1390962124349_637_788260286.    1/29/2014 5:21:23   d:\songs_new\target uganda\welcome56060_l.wav
1390962199363_744_789334537.    1/29/2014 5:23:03   d:\songs_new\target uganda\welcome56060_l.wav
1390962199363_744_789334537.    1/29/2014 5:23:06   d:\songs_new\target uganda\lang56060mix_l.wav
1390962199363_744_789334537.    1/29/2014 5:23:16   d:\songs_new\target uganda\sub2121_l.wav
1390962199363_744_789334537.    1/29/2014 5:23:03   d:\songs_new\target uganda\welcome56060_l.wav
1390962199363_744_789334537.    1/29/2014 5:23:06   d:\songs_new\target uganda\lang56060mix_l.wav
1390962199363_744_789334537.    1/29/2014 5:23:16   d:\songs_new\target uganda\sub2121_l.wav
1390962205310_742_787802027.    1/29/2014 5:23:13   d:\songs_new\target uganda\welcome56060_l.wav
```

Please take a look a the sample table.
I need to get the last played `media file` of corresponding `Master_ID`

For eg..

the data required for Master id `1390962109139_635_787802027` is `d:\songs_new\target uganda\pending_e.wav`

And so on...

I'm using MySQL server 5.5
SQL Yog

Answer (score 0):

Because it's mysql, you can use its funky grouping:

```
select * from (
    select master_id, media_file
    from mytable
    order by end_datetime desc
) x
group by 1
```

Grouping by just master_id means mysql will return the *first* row for each master_id. Ordering the data first means the returned row will be the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Using JOINS

```
SELECT * 
FROM sample_table AS s1
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(END_DATETIME)
            FROM sample_table 
            GROUP BY MASTER_ID
           ) AS max_master_id
ON (s1.END_DATETIME = max_master_id.END_DATETIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                 SELECT MASTER_ID,
                        media_file
                 FROM my_table 
                 ORDER BY end_datetime DESC
               ) a
 GROUP BY MASTER_ID;
```